# jQuery UI Dialog Queries + jQueryUI Queries

Tags: jquery-ui

I have setup the following jQuery UI Dialog within my document.ready() section, i.e:

```
        $("#dialog").dialog({
            autoOpen: false,
            bgiframe: true,
            resizable: false,
            modal: true,
            buttons: {
              'Ok': function() {               
                      $(this).dialog("close"); 
                    }
        }
    });
```

1) My question is which I am unsure of, is that within my javascript code, I have a counter, which when it hits a particular value, would like my dialog window to appear.

Unsure how to achieve or trigger this?

2) Within the jQueryUI website, I am trying to download the "Custom Theme" from http://jqueryui.com/download/?themeParams=%3Fctl%3Dthemeroller but nothing seem to happen, i.e no dialog save box appears.

Any ideas?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) If you want the dialog appear only when that condition is met, you should set the `autoOpen` option to `false`, later in your code, after you increment your counter variable, you should check its value and show it if the counter has the particular value you look for, i.e.:

```
// ...
counter++;
if (counter == 100) {
  $('#dialog').dialog('open');
}
// ...
```

2) To build your custom theme, use [ThemeRoller](http://themeroller.com/).

Comment: thanks CMS - I realised that I had autoOpen set to true - have now changed it back to false in this thread. Thanks also on the ThemeRoller - haven't really used this before.

Answer (score 1):

First question:

When you hit desired counter value do this:

```
$("#dialog").dialog("open");
```